# setting up hard drive partition for windows xp

Tags: windows

I'm using gparted on ubuntu via the live cd (11.10) to organize the partition to setup windows xp (sp3 (latest)) and im unsure of A: how to use gparted properly, and B: what settings to use for the partition to get it identifiable for the windows xp installation (to my understanding its hard to windows to see the hard drive after having a linux distro installed on it.

My ultimate goal is to use the WHOLE partition for windows, and erasing EVERYTHING on the drive. i understand i need to make the new partition an NTSF file system, but what about the other settings?

Comment: What other things? Just delete all partitions and create an NTFS one. ...and if not sure how to use Gparted, check out the manual. http://gparted.sourceforge.net/documentation.php

Comment: Do You have a free disc or already installed windows XP on it?

Comment: I just have one internal drive with nothing on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the partition, and do only one task at once.

No special settings, just remember to set the ntfs drive boot flag after it is created.

Comment: ive done everything you said and the same thing still happens, it just keeps restarting the laptop after the initial windows setup check. but to make sure, heres a screenshot of the partition setup, please advise of anything ive set wrong.

http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/1016/screenshotat20120114001.png

Comment: Looks good. Is it an XP with no SP integrated? If that is the case, it can only detect partitions smaller than ~130 GB. If this is the case, create a smaller partition with ~10GB + boot flag. You install the xp on this, update it, and later grow back the partition to 596 GB with a live cd. I am not sure by the way, what is the exact problem. But I would try this.